# #import "Project-Swift.h" comes some strange issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Project is mixed with `oc` and `swift`.

`#import "myProjectName-Swift.h"`  in the `AppDelegate.m`,:

Project is `Objective-c` language created by me, and using almost `swift` language to write. and In the `Appdelegate.m` I want to use `swift`'s class, and so

But unfortunate, my project occurs some `error` in `myProjectName-Swift.h`:

The code is below:

```
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, copy) 
NSString * _Nonnull ;)

+ (NSString * _Nonnull);
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, copy) 
NSString * _Nonnull ;)

+ (NSString * _Nonnull);

SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, strong) UIColor * _Nonnull APP_COLOR;)

+ (UIColor * _Nonnull)APP_COLOR;
```

The error are:

```
Expected ';' at end of declaration list.

cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocal

Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Expected ']'

Property requires fields to be named

Missing '[' at start of message send expression
```

And so on...

---

**Attension**
And In the global `swift`, I set Chinese characters variable like this:

```
class Global: NSObject {

}
```

---

**EDIT - 1**

Because I think a error point out the `static let "`'s `，so I annotation this line, project will not show this` error`. Or I delete the` ，`, will not show the error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support Unicode in identifiers (variable names, class names, method names etc), only in string literals (""). Only a subset of ASCII is allowed (start with _[a-zA-Z], +[0-9] afterwards).

Example:

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
  func () { }
}
```

This will break when you compile it in a mixed project. Instead you need to give it a valid Objective-C name, like so:

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
  @objc(unhappyFace)
  func () { }
}
```

which will compile (and you need to access it as `unhappyFace` on the ObjC side).

Or in your example you need to modify your Global object:

```
class Global: NSObject {
  @objc(emptyNumberNotAllowed)
  static let 手机号码不能为空 = "手机号码不能为空"
  ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, hnh. Do you think the Chinese character is out of `subset of ASCII` ? But I only delete the Chinese punctuation mark  `,`, so my project will not show that error. see my `EDIT - 1`.And I will try your method and reply, thanks your answer.